# How to get raw JSON text from Unirest response in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, unirest, jsonparser

I'm trying to send a POST request to a server, get the response, and parse it (it is a JSON file).

I am using Unirest for my POST request, simply as below:

```
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest
                .post("http://myserver.com/file")
                  .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                  .header("Postman-Token", "02ec2fa1-afdf-4a2a-a535-353424d99400")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body("{some JSON body}")
                .asJson();

        // retrieve the parsed JSONObject from the response
        JSONObject myObj = response.getBody().getObject();
        // extract fields from the object
        String msg = myObj.toString();

        System.out.println(msg);
```

But I have problems getting the **raw JSON text** (I want to use `JSONPath` to parse the response).

How can I do that? All my attempts calling `toString()` methods failed so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unirest API supports this out of the box - Use `asString()` instead of `asJson()` to get the response as `HttpResponse<String>`.

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest
                .post("http://myserver.com/file")
                  .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                  .header("Postman-Token", "02ec2fa1-afdf-4a2a-a535-353424d99400")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body("{some JSON body}")
                .asString();
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Comment: Interesting. Apparently my eclipse was not outputing this! In a shell I see the response!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = response.getRawBody();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int result = bis.read();
while(result != -1) {
    buf.write((byte) result);
    result = bis.read();
}

String rawJson = buf.toString("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't return String. It is `InputStream`.

Comment: You can read an inputstream into a String.  You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-to-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: yes, I know. But thinking if there is an easier way to do that (btw, please post the full answer so I can mark you as best answer)